# Consulta MySql resultados confusos

Tags: java, mysql

Eu tenho que fazer uma consulta mysql através de um método Java.
Essa é a sql que fiz para testar se funciona:

`select * from servicos S, clientes C, motores M
where C.nome = "Claudio Fernando Pires"
group by ordemServico`

Teoricamente ele devia trazer somente os serviços cujo o cliente fosse "Claudio Fernando Pires" certo? Me corrijam se estiver enganado.

Só que ele trás todos os serviços, mesmo sendo de ouro cliente como de "Claudio Fernando Pires", o mesmo acontece com qualquer outro parâmetro do cliente ou motor.

Este é meu método em Java:

```
public List<Servico> pesquisarServicos(String nomeCliente, String endereco, String marcaMotor, String modeloMotor) {

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes C, motores M, servicos S "
            + "WHERE  C.nome LIKE ? AND C.endereco  LIKE ? AND M.marcaMotor LIKE ? AND M.modeloMotor LIKE ?"
            + "GROUP BY ordemServico";

    ResultSet listaResultados = null;
    List<Servico> servicos = new ArrayList();


    try {
        PreparedStatement comando = BD.conection.prepareStatement(sql);
            comando.setString(1, nomeCliente+"%");
            comando.setString(2, "%"+endereco+"%");
            comando.setString(3, marcaMotor+"%");
            comando.setString(4, modeloMotor+"%");

        listaResultados = comando.executeQuery();
        Servico servico;

        while (listaResultados.next()) {
            servico = new Servico();
            servico.setCliente(ControleCliente.buscarCliente(listaResultados.getString("CPF")));
            servico.setDataServico(listaResultados.getString("dataServico"));
            servico.setDescricaoServico(listaResultados.getString("observacao"));
            servico.setFormaPagamento(Servico.getFormaPagamento(listaResultados.getInt("formaPagamento")));
            servico.setMotor(ControleMotor.buscarMotor(listaResultados.getString("numMotor")));
            servico.setOrdemServico(listaResultados.getString("ordemServico"));
            servico.setTipoSevico(Servico.getTipoServico(listaResultados.getInt("tipoServico")));
            servico.setValorServico(listaResultados.getDouble("valorServico"));
            servicos.add(servico);
        }
        listaResultados.close();
        comando.close();
        System.out.println("Lista Resultante="+servicos.size());
    } catch (SQLException excessaoSQL) {
        excessaoSQL.printStackTrace();
    }
    return servicos;
}
```

Apresenta o mesmo problema na minha view escrita em Java.

Olha o resultado preenchendo o filtro nome:
[image: Com o filtro nome]

Se eu trocar o filtro Nome:
[image: Com outro nome]
Alguma sugestão de o que que esta acontecendo e como fazer a busca funcionar, para os dois casos?

Estes são os registros na tabela Serviços:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

deveria trazer os registros referente ao cliente a qual informei algum atributo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

neste caso usei um atributo da própria tabela Serviços, mais essa é a ideia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizaria JOIN nesse caso, mais confiável para o que você esta querendo fazer:

```
SELECT s.atributo_servico1, s.atributo_servico2 FROM servicos s
JOIN clientes c ON c.codigo = s.cliente
WHERE c.nome LIKE "Claudio Fernando Pires"
GROUP BY s.ordem_servico;
```

Se precisar um JOIN com outra tabela para resgatar os valores dessa outra tabela basta colocar abaixo do JOIN do cliente e assim por diante.

**Dicas**

Para padronização no banco de dados os campos devem ser `ordem_servico` invés de `ordemServico`. Tudo bem declarar uma variável `ordemServico` no Java, mas dificilmente observamos isso nos bancos de dados relacionais.

Recomendo também invés de utilizar `*` diretamente no SELECT você mencionasse os campos das tabelas `c.codigo, c.nome_cliente` e assim por diante para você ter um maior controle dos campos que serão retornados.

Comment: Não funcionou da maneira que sugeriu. Vou tentar te explicar de uma outra maneira:

Eu tenho um serviço que tem como chave o cpf do cliente, isso que os relaciona, o mesmo para o motor, sendo o numero de serie a chave.
O que preciso fazer e por exemplo: busca um serviço informando o nome do cliente o join funcionou em não duplicar os registros, o que vinha acontecendo. Porém ele fica do jeito ai em cima. Tipo, isso que to tentado fazer seria possível passando do Java pra mysql?

Comment: Já experimentou agrupar pelo CPF?

Comment: Tenho 4 registro no banco, ele me trouxe 2 resultados tanto para para:
GROUP BY C.cpf ou GROUP BY S.clienteId.
Pelo que eu entendi, GROUP BY ele restringe minha a busca a 1 item de cada chave para o GROUP BY que eu informei certo?
Neste caso eu posso ter mais de um registro para cada cliente ou motor, então restringindo pela ordem_servico seria o suficiente para ele não duplicar meus registros como acontecia anteriormente.

Comment: Esses 4 registros são tudo de um serviço só, isso? E você quer mostrar apenas 1? E o agrupamento pelo identificador do serviço, seria uma boa solução? E assim somaria o valor do serviço resultando o total corretamente.

Comment: Não, são todos distintos, podem ter valor idênticos, mais a ordem_servico faz ele serem diferentes. O que pretendo é trazer um serviço informando uma característica ou do motor ou do cliente. Consegue entender?

Comment: Poderia colocar uma imagem de como deveria ficar o resultado e editar a pergunta?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30703/discussion-between-giancarlo-abel-giulian-and-julio-cesar-da-silva-barros).

Comment: Galera, o Giancarlo me ajudou bastante, agora cheguei no ponto onde quando eu informo algum atributo para fazer a filtragem, o mesmo não me retorna item algum, tanto em sql quanto na sql feita no método java. Alguma dica?